# jquery select the value and show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used jquery, when I click on the dropdown it will take the value and will search related to the input. But it is not taking the value correctly. If I click on one value it is taking the next value.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Roles", ViewData["Roles"] as SelectList,"Select" , new {onchange = "javascript:ddlRoleChanged();", id="ddlRoles",  @class = "dropdownStyle2"})%>
```

This is my dropdown. I am taking the id and pass into jquery like the following,

```
function ddlRoleChanged() {debugger;
     var selectedValue = $('#ddlRoles').val();
     window.location = '/home/homepage?variable=' + selectedValue.valueOf();
 };
```

`selectedvalue` is taking the value. But it is not coming correctly. Please help me.

Comment: Please add the generated HTML markup

Comment: If you have a specific problem please explain it properly. *"But it is not coming correctly"* is not a useful problem description.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini  my question is different from another one.. it is not duplicate one.

Comment: @Duk You appear to be asking how to get the selected value in a <select> tag in jquery, as per your title, and your code. The duplicate marked asks the same, and is answered. If you have a different question, ask a new question, or edit this one including the title to make it clear what you're really asking.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini yes you are correct. How do i know if already some people asked.. I want this requirement, so i put this question. any way i ll ask different question if already exists.

Comment: @Duk When you start typing your question this site shows you similar questions - if one of them is the same thing, stop typing your question and enjoy the fact it's already been answered and off ya go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
function ddlRoleChanged() {debugger;
  var selectedValue = $('#ddlRoles option:selected').val();
  window.location = '/home/homepage?variable=' + selectedValue.valueOf();
};
```

Comment: Why should the OP try that? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with their code.

Comment: @FelixKling: its just an alternative solution to the OP`s Question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var selectedValue = $('#ddlRoles').val();
```

will give you the selected value of the drop down element.
 Use this to get the selected options text.

```
$('#ur dropdown id:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#ddlRoles').change(function(){
         var selectedValue = $(this).val();
         location.href = '/home/homepage?variable=' + selectedValue ;
    });
});
```

try this